# Converting the shapefile of google drive to geometry of GEE in Colab

Tags: shapefile, google-earth-engine, geometry, convert, google-drive

I uploaded district's shapefile into google drive, and then read it from google drive using the below method:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
shapefile = gpd.read_file("shapefile.shp")
```

But I want to convert it as geometry object of GEE, so that I can call the clip function of Image of GEE, how can I do?

Answer (score 0):

One method is to import it to Assets, after zipping the shapefile; as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/importing).

Answer (score 0):

I found this approach (probably came frome somewhere in the internet).

So first you create a function to convert the input file to a json and then extract the coordinates. Then you send this into the `ee.Geometry`

For example:

```
#auxiliar function to convert to json
def coords_from_gpd(shape_in):
  return eval(shape_in.to_json())['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates']

#loading to GEE - polygon cant be very complex it seems 
a_file =  ee.Geometry.Polygon(coords_from_gpd(a_shape))
```